# How to remove hyper link if payment method CASH, it should be displayed on payment method check row in Acumatica, below is the screen shot

Tags: acumatica

How to remove hyper link if payment method CASH, it should be displayed on payment method check row in Acumatica, below is the screen shot.

its a grid view control

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Aspx control property `LinkCommand` applies to the whole column.

You can set aspx control property `MatrixMode` to true to allow different enabled state per row. And then call `PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled` to disable link per row. However the links will still be functional and when clicked will display an error message for rows which have link disabled.

To remove link per row, you can set LinkCommand to false on original link column to remove link contol. And then create a new link column where you remove the field text value to hide the link.

[image]